# If A is a matrix satisfying $A^3 + 4A - 2I = 0$, explain why A is invertible...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

If A is a matrix  satisfying $A^3 + 4A - 2I = 0$, explain why A is invertible.

-I understand that I can easily find a matrix that fits this condition and prove that its determinant is not zero, but how would I prove this for all A matrices as opposed to a specific example. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

One has: $$A(A^2+4A)=2I.$$
Therefore: $$A\left(\frac{1}{2}A^2+2A\right)=I.$$
Hence $A$ is right invertible and thus invertible.

**N.B.** You have to assume that $2$ is invertible in the ring from which $A$ takes its entries.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that your relation is equivalent to
$$A\left(\frac{1}{2}A^2+2A\right)=I.$$

Comment: What a weird notation for the $Id$ :~).

Comment: he-he not weird, instead natural :D

Comment: @Surb, why the change? why don't you like my $1\!\!1$?

Comment: It's not a common way to denote the identity matrix.

Comment: it is common in my posts

Comment: @Surb See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11857/arbitrarily-editing-an-askers-notation-to-fit-your-own-preferences).

Comment: @janmarqz Feel free to change back the notation.Only mods hold any sort of authority over you.

Comment: If it's very important for you to use $1\!\!1$, just do it ! but I don't see the point of complicate unnecessarily the notation. Anyway, it's just a detail...  @janmarqz

Answer (score 2):

You can see that 
$$\det(A^3+4A)=\det(A)\times\det(A^2+4I)=\det(2I)\neq 0,$$ which implies $\det(A)\neq0$ and so $A$ is invertible.

Comment: The fact that $A^3+4A-2I=0$ says much more that $A$ is invertible :-)

Comment: @Surb : Yes I agree, the good answer was given at the same moment and I prefer it too.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the relation as 
$$\frac12 A(A^2+4I)=I,$$
and you get $$A^{-1}=\frac12(A^2+4I).$$